# Possible to merge as a 16bit grayscale raster from 8bit heightmaps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm importing many 8bit heightmaps and merging them in QGIS. However I notice that smaller details dissapear because of the 8bit export.

Is it it possible to merge the heightmaps into a 16bit greyscale?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Merge tool in QGIS allows you to choose the output data type.
[image]

Here is a description of the data type choices.
[image]

Comment: I've tested with these a little, and the Int types just crunch the data all the way down. Example of a Int16 merger [before and after](https://imgur.com/a/bSW5elm).

I've used  Float64 aswell mainly, but it produces the exact loss of detail I've mentioned.
Example in the same Imgur link of a random island before and after merging with Float64.

Is there any way to maintain the detail after merging?

There's also the problem that even after merging, QGIS does agree that the file is indeed a 64bit image, exporting it and opening in GIMP claims that it is a 8bit RGB image.